# Running pandoc/rmarkdown with openout_any=a

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc

I want to run `openout_any=a` in order to compile my files (they start with a dot). How can I do this when using Pandoc/Rmarkdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested in the future:

It turned out to be as simple as running `openout_any=a` + `your compilation statement`. For example:

```bash
openout_any=a Rscript -e "library(rmarkdown); rmarkdown::render('.hello.Rmd', 'pdf_document')"
```

Hope it helps.